# Fourier Series and Inner Product

Tags: fourier-series

When working with Fourier series, the inner product is defined as
$$\int_{-L}^L f(x)g(x)dx$$

I see this definition everywhere and we know that $\rm{sin}\big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\big)$ and $\rm{cos}\big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\big)$ will form a orthogonal basis, but not orthonormal.

My question is: why is not more usual to define the inner product as
$$\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^L f(x)g(x)dx$$ ?

Because with this definition, the previous basis will be orthonormal.

I think that the basis will be precisely $\Big\{ \frac{1}{2},\rm{sin}\big(\frac{\pi x}{L}\big),\rm{cos}\big(\frac{\pi x}{L}\big),\rm{sin}\big(\frac{2\pi x}{L}\big),\rm{cos}\big(\frac{2\pi x}{L}\big),\ldots \Big\} $.

Comment: Actually, people often divide by L: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series

Comment: Well...in that case I think I'll blame my books XD

Comment: @julien If is there some mistake in my english, please feel free to edit.

Comment: I'll let native english speakers do that if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An inner product is bilinear form that's symmetric definite positive, so whatever you multiply this inner product by positive real, it's still an inner product.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I want to know.

Comment: You're welcome.